# ifelse for the entire group (not only one row)

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I'm trying to apply `ifelse` for the entire group. I know this sounds unclear, so let me provide a reproducible example. Consider the following data frame.

```
id = rep(c(1:3), each = 5)
date = rep(seq.Date(as_date("2010-01-01"), as_date("2010-01-05"), by = "day"), 3)
value = c(1:4, NA, 3:5, NA, 5, NA, 1:4)

df <- data.frame(id, date, value)
```

Suppose I want to create a column "missing" which takes value 1 for the entire group (not only the corresponding row) if "value" column is `NA` for date = 2010-01-05.

```
df %>% group_by(id) %>% mutate(missing = ifelse(value %in% NA & date == "2010-01-05", 1, 0))
```

I tried piping `group_by(id)` before the `ifelse` command like above hoping that ifelse value will be populated by group, but it's not working. Indeed it produces the same result as the code below which does not have `group_by` pipe.

```
df %>% mutate(missing = ifelse(value %in% NA & date == "2010-01-05", 1, 0))
```

At the end of the day, I want my data to look like

```
df2
   id       date value missing
1   1 2010-01-01     1       1
2   1 2010-01-02     2       1
3   1 2010-01-03     3       1
4   1 2010-01-04     4       1
5   1 2010-01-05    NA       1
6   2 2010-01-01     3       0
7   2 2010-01-02     4       0
8   2 2010-01-03     5       0
9   2 2010-01-04    NA       0
10  2 2010-01-05     5       0
11  3 2010-01-01    NA       0
12  3 2010-01-02     1       0
13  3 2010-01-03     2       0
14  3 2010-01-04     3       0
15  3 2010-01-05     4       0
```

Is there a way I can do this by somehow tweaking `ifelse`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do,

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
 group_by(id) %>% 
 mutate(res = as.integer(is.na(value[date == "2010-01-05"])))
```

which gives,

> ```
> id date       value   res
>    <int> <date>     <dbl> <int>
>  1     1 2010-01-01     1     1
>  2     1 2010-01-02     2     1
>  3     1 2010-01-03     3     1
>  4     1 2010-01-04     4     1
>  5     1 2010-01-05    NA     1
>  6     2 2010-01-01     3     0
>  7     2 2010-01-02     4     0
>  8     2 2010-01-03     5     0
>  9     2 2010-01-04    NA     0
> 10     2 2010-01-05     5     0
> 11     3 2010-01-01    NA     0
> 12     3 2010-01-02     1     0
> 13     3 2010-01-03     2     0
> 14     3 2010-01-04     3     0
> 15     3 2010-01-05     4     0
> ```

Comment: This is great! Do you have a get around when value takes other conditions that NA? (In other words, when ```is.na``` cannot be used). To be concrete, if the condition is ```value == 5```?

Comment: Yes. It would go something like `df %>% group_by(id) %>% mutate(res = as.integer(value[date == '2010-01-015] == 5))`